eMMC data timeout on linux 4.19 kernel
Our box boots off of eMMC drive. Our image is based on linux 4.19 kernel. We run the eMMC in SDR50 mode, and boot the kernel with sdhci.append_quirks2=0x40 argument. We have 2 partitions and format the drive with ext3 filesystem.
After the box is up for a long time where reads and writes are fine, we get hit with this timeout:
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:11 2024] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:11 2024] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:11 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0xd3c00000 | Version:  0x00001002
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:11 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000008
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:11 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00800818 | Trn mode: 0x00000033
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0206 | Host ctl: 0x00000007
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000207
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000c | Int stat: 0x00000000
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x000000ff
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x75fec8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002501
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x00c80064
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0xffffffff
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x320f5903 | Resp[3]:  0x00d04f01
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:12 2024] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0xd3c00000 | Version:  0x00001002
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000008
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00800818 | Trn mode: 0x00000033
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0206 | Host ctl: 0x00000007
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000207
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000c | Int stat: 0x00000000
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:23 2024] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x000000ff
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:24 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x75fec8b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002501
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:24 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x00c80064
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:24 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0xffffffff
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:24 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x320f5903 | Resp[3]:  0x00d04f01
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:24 2024] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:24 2024] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:36 2024] mmc0: cache flush error -110
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:36 2024] CANARY: task jbd2/mmcblk0p1- pid 314 was blocked in D state for 12 seconds
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:37 2024] mmc0: tried to HW reset card, got error -110
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:37 2024] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8390680
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:37 2024] sdhci-pci 0000:00:14.7: error -110 requesting status
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:37 2024] mmc0: cache flush error -110
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:38 2024] mmc0: tried to HW reset card, got error -110
[Mon Jan 29 00:07:38 2024] mmcblk0: recovery failed!

I see above register dump is called from sdhci_timeout_data_timer() function in drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c.

When does this data timeout happen?
Perhaps CRC errors? How do I reproduce such timeout?
Can we recover from this state without rebooting? Perhaps use mmc_test kernel module for this?

Appreciate if anyone who knows eMMC protocol or who has worked on eMMC driver has any idea of what is going on.
